Why the Cursor query is fetching records successfully but not fetching the values?
Below is the SQL package which is going to be a part of a script. In this package the cursor used is fetching sufficient records as required, but not working when I am incorporating in this package. On changing the cursor while putting less where conditions, it works just fine. But somehow this is the correct cursor.
SET serveroutput ON;
CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE CUSTOM.FINPACK_WELDUMMY AS
PROCEDURE FINPROC_WELDUMMY(inp_str VARCHAR2,
                        out_retCode OUT NUMBER,
                        out_rec OUT VARCHAR2);
END FINPACK_WELDUMMY;
/
CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE BODY CUSTOM.FINPACK_WELDUMMY AS
-------------------------------------------------------------------
-- Declaring the variables to be used in the Procedure
-------------------------------------------------------------------
    outArr                      TBAADM.basp0099.ArrayType;
    v_bodDate                   DATE;
    v_bank_id                   TBAADM.GAM.BANK_ID%type;
    v_acid                      VARCHAR2(11 CHAR);
    v_lacid                     VARCHAR2(11 CHAR);
    v_cif_id                    VARCHAR2(50 CHAR);
    v_acct_cls_flg              VARCHAR2(1);
    v_schm_code                 VARCHAR2(20);
    v_address_id                NUMBER(38);
    v_count                     VARCHAR2(3 CHAR);
    v_advance_instl             NUMBER(20,4);
    v_agreement_no              VARCHAR2(200);
    v_amtfin                    NUMBER(20,4);
    v_tenure                    NUMBER(3);
    v_title                     NVARCHAR2(75);
    v_fname                     NVARCHAR2(120);
    v_mname                     NVARCHAR2(120);
    v_lname                     NVARCHAR2(150);
    v_address1                  NVARCHAR2(200 CHAR);
    v_address2                  NVARCHAR2(200 CHAR);
    v_address3                  NVARCHAR2(200 CHAR);
    v_address4                  VARCHAR2(80 CHAR);
    v_landmark                  VARCHAR2(100);
    v_city                      NVARCHAR2(200 CHAR);
    v_statedesc                 NVARCHAR2(200 CHAR);
    v_zipcode                   NVARCHAR2(100 CHAR);
    v_branchdesc                VARCHAR2(132 CHAR);
    v_instl_num                 NUMBER(3);
    v_due_date                  DATE;
    v_instl_amt                 NUMBER(20,4);
    v_dmd_amt                   NUMBER(20,2);
    v_dflt_principal_flow_id    VARCHAR2(100);
    v_acct_crncy_code           VARCHAR2(3 CHAR);
    v_princomp                  NUMBER(20,4);
    v_intcomp                   NUMBER(20,4);
    v_endbal                    NUMBER(20,2);
    v_repaymode                 CHAR(3);
    v_effrate                   VARCHAR2(100);
    v_promotionid               VARCHAR2(200);
    v_cust_segment_code         VARCHAR2(200);
    v_cust_service_code         VARCHAR2(200);
    v_product_pre_fix           VARCHAR2(200);
    v_dob                       VARCHAR2(200);
    v_product                   VARCHAR2(16 CHAR);
    v_vendor                    VARCHAR2(200);  
    v_pre_printed_stationary    VARCHAR2(200);
    v_file_attchment_name       VARCHAR2(200);
    v_psw                       VARCHAR2(200);  
    v_identifier                VARCHAR2(200);  
    v_identifier2               VARCHAR2(200);
    v_amort_printing            VARCHAR2(200);
    v_month                     VARCHAR2(200);
    v_premi1                    VARCHAR2(200);
    v_preemi2                   VARCHAR2(200);  
    v_disbursed_amount          VARCHAR2(200);
    v_awb_no                    VARCHAR2(200);
    v_email                     NVARCHAR2(75);
    v_area                      VARCHAR2(200);      
    v_sc_code                   VARCHAR2(200);
    v_mobile_no                 NVARCHAR2(37.5);
    v_sol_id                    VARCHAR2(8 CHAR);

-------------------------------------------------------------------
--Cursor declaration
--This cursor will fetch all the LOAN accounts.
-------------------------------------------------------------------

    CURSOR getCustDetail 
        (
            v_bodDate                   DATE,
            v_bank_id                   TBAADM.GAM.BANK_ID%TYPE
        ) IS
        SELECT  A.ACID, A.TRAN_DATE, B.SRL_NUM, B.INTEREST_AMOUNT, B.SHDL_BALANCE, C.DFLT_PRINCIPAL_FLOW_ID, D.SOL_ID, D.ACCT_CLS_FLG, D.SCHM_CODE, D.ACID, D.ACCT_CRNCY_CODE, D.CIF_ID
        FROM    TBAADM.LTD A, TBAADM.LSBT B, TBAADM.LSP C, TBAADM.GAM D
        WHERE   A.TRAN_DATE = TO_DATE(v_bodDate,'DD-MM-YYYY') - 1
        AND     D.ACID = A.ACID 
        AND     B.ACID = A.ACID     
        AND     A.FLOW_ID = C.DFLT_DISBMNT_FLOW_ID
        AND     D.SCHM_CODE = C.SCHM_CODE
        AND     A.BANK_ID = D.BANK_ID AND B.BANK_ID = D.BANK_ID
        AND     C.BANK_ID = D.BANK_ID
        AND     A.DEL_FLG = 'N' AND C.DEL_FLG = 'N'
        AND     D.DEL_FLG = 'N'
        AND     D.SCHM_TYPE = 'LAA'
        AND     A.ENTITY_CRE_FLG = 'Y'
        AND     D.ENTITY_CRE_FLG = 'Y';

-----------------------------------------------------------
------------------ Procedure Body 1------------------------
-----------------------------------------------------------
PROCEDURE FINPROC_WELDUMMY(inp_str IN VARCHAR2,
                            out_retCode OUT NUMBER,
                            out_rec OUT VARCHAR2) AS

  BEGIN
    -- Your existing code goes here
    out_rec := NULL;
    out_retCode := 0;

    TBAADM.basp0099.formInputArr (inp_str, OutArr);
    v_bodDate  := TO_DATE(OutArr(0),'DD-MM-YYYY');
    v_bank_id  := OutArr(1);
    
        IF(NOT getCustDetail%ISOPEN) THEN
      --{
          OPEN getCustDetail(v_bodDate,v_bank_id);
      --}
        END IF;  

    IF getCustDetail%ISOPEN THEN
      --{
      FETCH getCustDetail INTO v_lacid, v_due_date, v_count, v_intcomp, v_princomp, v_dflt_principal_flow_id, v_sol_id, v_acct_cls_flg, v_schm_code, v_acid, v_acct_crncy_code, v_cif_id;
      --}
    END IF;

    IF getCustDetail%NOTFOUND THEN
      --{
      CLOSE getCustDetail;
      out_retCode  := 1;
      DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('out_retCode: ' || out_retCode);
      RETURN;
      --}
    END IF;
--------------------------------------------------------
    -- FECTHING ACCOUNT DETAILS AFTER CURSOR
--------------------------------------------------------
    BEGIN
            SELECT  SOL_DESC
            INTO    v_branchdesc
            FROM    TBAADM.SOL
            WHERE   SOL_ID = v_sol_id
            AND     DEL_FLG = 'N'
            AND     BANK_ID = v_bank_id;
            EXCEPTION
                WHEN NO_DATA_FOUND THEN
                v_branchdesc := NULL;
    END;
       
    BEGIN
        SELECT
            nvl(
                abs(INTEREST_RATE), 0
            )
        INTO 
            v_effrate
        FROM
            TBAADM.EIT
        WHERE
            ENTITY_ID = v_acid
            AND BANK_ID = v_bank_id
            AND ENTITY_TYPE = 'ACCNT';

        EXCEPTION
            WHEN NO_DATA_FOUND THEN
                v_effrate := NULL;
    END;
    
    BEGIN
            SELECT
                nvl(
                        SUM(DMD_AMT), 0
                    )
            INTO v_dmd_amt
            FROM
                    TBAADM.LDT
            WHERE
                ACID = v_acid
                AND BANK_ID = v_bank_id
                AND DMD_FLOW_ID = v_dflt_principal_flow_id;

            EXCEPTION
            WHEN NO_DATA_FOUND THEN
                    v_dmd_amt := NULL;
    END;       
            
    BEGIN
        SELECT  UPFRONT_INSTL_INT_AMT, DIS_AMT
        INTO    v_advance_instl, v_amtfin
        FROM    TBAADM.LAM
        WHERE   ACID = v_acid
        AND     DEL_FLG = 'N'
        AND     ENTITY_CRE_FLG = 'Y'
        AND     BANK_ID = v_bank_id;
        EXCEPTION
            WHEN NO_DATA_FOUND THEN
            v_advance_instl := NULL;
            v_amtfin := NULL;
    END;   

    BEGIN
    SELECT  NUM_OF_DMDS, FLOW_AMT, NUM_OF_FLOWS
    INTO    v_instl_num, v_instl_amt, v_tenure
    FROM    TBAADM.LRS
    WHERE   ACID = v_acid
    AND     DEL_FLG = 'N'
    AND     BANK_ID = v_bank_id
    AND     FLOW_ID = v_dflt_principal_flow_id
    AND     ENTITY_CRE_FLG = 'Y';
    EXCEPTION
        WHEN NO_DATA_FOUND THEN
        v_instl_num := NULL;
        v_instl_amt := NULL;
        v_tenure := NULL;
    END; 

    BEGIN
        SELECT A.SEGMENTATION_CLASS, A.SUBSEGMENT, B.SALUTATION, B.CUST_FIRST_NAME, B.CUST_MIDDLE_NAME, B.CUST_LAST_NAME, B.EMAIL, B.PHONE_CELL, B.CUST_DOB
        INTO v_cust_segment_code,v_cust_service_code, v_title, v_fname, v_mname, v_lname, v_email, v_mobile_no, v_dob
        FROM CRMUSER.PSYCHOGRAPHIC A,CRMUSER.ACCOUNTS B
        WHERE A.ACCOUNTID = B.ACCOUNTID
        AND A.BANK_ID = v_bank_id AND B.BANK_ID = v_bank_id
        AND A.ORGKEY = v_cif_id AND B.ORGKEY = v_cif_id;
        EXCEPTION
        WHEN NO_DATA_FOUND THEN
        v_cust_segment_code := 'NA';
        v_cust_service_code := 'NA';
        v_title := 'NA';
        v_fname := 'NA';
        v_mname := 'NA';
        v_lname := 'NA';
        v_email := 'NA';
        v_mobile_no := 'NA';
        v_dob := 'NA';
    END;       
    
    BEGIN
        SELECT ADDRESS_LINE1,ADDRESS_LINE2, ADDRESS_LINE3, CITY, STATE, ZIP
        INTO v_address1, v_address2, v_address3, v_city, v_statedesc, v_zipcode
        FROM CRMUSER.ADDRESS
        WHERE ACCOUNTID = v_acid
        AND BANK_ID = v_bank_id;
        EXCEPTION
        WHEN NO_DATA_FOUND THEN
        v_address1 := 'NA';
        v_address2 := 'NA';
        v_address3 := 'NA';
        v_city := 'NA';
        v_statedesc := NULL;
        v_zipcode := NULL;
    END;

    BEGIN
        v_address4                  := NULL;
        v_landmark                  := NULL;
        v_vendor                    := NULL;
        v_pre_printed_stationary    := NULL;
        v_file_attchment_name       := NULL;
        v_psw                       := NULL;
        v_identifier                := NULL;
        v_month                     := NULL;
        v_amort_printing            := 'Y'; 
        v_premi1                    := 'NA';
        v_preemi2                   :='NA';
        v_disbursed_amount          :='NA';
        v_awb_no                    :='NA';
        v_area                      :='NA';
        v_sc_code                   :='NA';
    END;

    out_rec := v_count || '|' || v_advance_instl || '|' || v_agreement_no || '|' || v_amtfin || '|' || v_tenure || '|' || v_title || '|' || v_fname || '|' || v_mname || '|' || v_lname || '|' || v_address1 || '|' || v_address2 || '|' || v_address3 || '|' || v_address4 || '|' || v_landmark || '|' || v_city || '|' || v_statedesc || '|' || v_zipcode || '|' || v_branchdesc || '|' || v_instl_num || '|' || v_due_date || '|' || v_instl_amt || '|' || v_dmd_amt || '|' || v_dflt_principal_flow_id || '|' || v_princomp || '|' || v_intcomp || '|' || v_endbal || '|' || v_repaymode || '|' || v_effrate || '|' || v_promotionid || '|' || v_cust_segment_code || '|' || v_cust_service_code || '|' || v_product_pre_fix || '|' || v_dob || '|' || v_product|| '|' || v_vendor || '|' || v_pre_printed_stationary || '|' || v_file_attchment_name || '|' || v_psw || '|' || v_identifier || '|' || v_identifier2 || '|' || v_amort_printing || '|' || v_month || '|' || v_premi1 || '|' || v_preemi2 || '|' || v_disbursed_amount || '|' || v_awb_no || '|' || v_email
    || '|' || v_area || '|' || v_sc_code || '|' || v_mobile_no || '|' || v_sol_id;


END FINPROC_WELDUMMY;


END FINPACK_WELDUMMY;
/
-------------------------------------------------------
-- Execution grants are given to Tbacust Tbautil Tbagen
-------------------------------------------------------
/
DROP SYNONYM CUSTOM.C_FINPACK_WELDUMMY;
/
CREATE SYNONYM CUSTOM.C_FINPACK_WELDUMMY FOR CUSTOM.FINPACK_WELDUMMY;
/
GRANT EXECUTE ON CUSTOM.FINPACK_WELDUMMY TO TBAGEN,TBAUTIL,TBAADM;
/
SHOW ERRORS;



I could not refine the cursor more because my senior has asked me to keep it like this only.

Please [edit] the question to include a [MRE] with a MINIMAL example of the problem; include the CREATE TABLE and INSERT statements for your sample data so we can execute the package; an English (not code) explanation of the logic that you want to implement; the issues/errors with your minimal example; and the expected output for the sample data. At the moment you have a poorly explained problem with a large amount of code (most of which is probably irrelevant to the problem) and none of the tables/data that would allow us to run the procedure which makes it very hard to understand.

You're only retrieving a single row from the cursor. Typically you would loop around the cursor and fetch all the rows. What is it you intend to do with all the rows once you've fetched them? Also, all those SELECT statements could be (assuming there predicates are fetching at most a single row) merged into the cursor via outer joins. And I'd look to change the cursor to use ANSI join syntax, not the out-dated style as it is at present.

You are declaring the variables and cursor in the package and not in the procedure within the package. Move all the variable and cursor declarations into the procedure (between the AS and BEGIN keywords).
